# Upload Interface with Primefaces 4.0 doesn't fire

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'm doing a webapplication running on an Apache Tomcat 7 using Primefaces 4.0.
Trying to realize an upload interface similar to the Primefaces ShowCase, the upload interface doesn't fire any function in the backing bean:

Here's what I included directly in my body (I also  tried without "multiple", "value", advanced mode, "actionListener" attributes)

```
                            <p:fileUpload id="fileupload_" 
                            value="#{userWizard.fu.uploadedFile}" 
                            fileUploadListener="#{userWizard.fu.addFileToAttachment}" 
                            actionListener="#{userWizard.fu.listener}" 
                            mode="advanced"
                            dragDropSupport="false"
                            update="messages"
                            multiple="false"
                            sizeLimit="50000000"
                            fileLimit="3" 
                            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
                            auto="true"/>
        <p:growl id="messages"  showDetail="true" />
```

And here is my backing bean:

```
 import java.util.LinkedList;
 import java.util.List;
 import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
 import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;
 import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
 import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
 import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

 @ManagedBean
 @SessionScoped
public class FileUpload {  

private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

List<UploadedFile> files = new LinkedList<UploadedFile>();

public FileUpload() 
{}

public List<UploadedFile> getFiles() {
    System.out.println( "< getFiles > ");
    return files;
}

public void setFiles(List<UploadedFile> files) {
    System.out.println( "< setFiles > ");
    this.files = files;
}

public void addFileToAttachment(FileUploadEvent event)
{
    System.out.println("addfile");
    System.out.println( "upload > " + event.getFile().getFileName());
    files.add(event.getFile());
}

public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
    System.out.println( "< getFile > ");
    return uploadedFile;
}

public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
    System.out.println( "< setFile > ");
    this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
}

public void listener(ActionEvent ae)
{
    System.out.println("listener");
}



public void insert()
{
    System.out.println( "insert");
    if(uploadedFile !=null)
    {
        System.out.println( "  > " + uploadedFile.getFileName());
    }
}

}
```

I see the upload interface on my webpage and the files seem uploaded, but none of the listeners/setters println is printed on my output. A regular commandbutton with its listener in my FileUpload bean fires it normally.

Using Primefaces 4.0, I didn't add the FileUpload filter in my web.xml file (I also tried to add it just in case, but it didn't work any better).

Also, commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar and commons-io-2.4.jar are in the libraries of my project.

Does anyone have an idea of where my problem could be ?

Thank you

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imiBwk_xqaE

Comment: Actually, there are several steps to achieve this. Either follow the video tutorial above or google it for more.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple checks, I realized that I used javax.faces-2.1 instead of 2.2.
Combined with javax.servlet API and still in Primefaces 4.0 my problem now seems solved.

Comment: By your answer, looks like a misconfiguration in your JSF 2.2 + PrimeFaces 4 project...

Answer (score 0):

In your code `fileUploadListener="#{userWizard.fu.addFileToAttachment}"`, but you just post `FileUpload.java`. 
I did not see your `userWizard` bean and `addFileToAttachment` listener method. But, try as below

Configure `web.xml` configuration as below :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>51200</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Your `h:form` must be like `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">`.

For multiple upload example :

multipleupload.xthml

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{MultipleUploadActionBean.handleProposalAttachment}"  
                    mode="advanced" multiple="true" sizeLimit="3000000"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" id="attachment"/>
</h:form>
```

MultipleUploadActionBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "MultipleUploadActionBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MultipleUploadActionBean {
    private List<UploadedFile> uploadFileList = new ArrayList<UploadedFile>();

    public void handleProposalAttachment(FileUploadEvent event) {
        UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
        uploadFileList.add(uploadedFile);
    }
}
```

For single upload example :

singleupload.xthml

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload value="#{SingleUploadActionBean.uploadedFile}" mode="simple"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" actionListener="#{SingleUploadActionBean.upload}"/> 
</h:form>
```

SingleUploadActionBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "SingleUploadActionBean")
@ViewScoped
public class SingleUploadActionBean {
    private UploadedFile uploadedFile;
    //getter & setter

    public void upload() {
        //your operation
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I finally managed to solve my problem by updating one of the libraries (I had JSF 2.1, replaced it by 2.2, and everything finally worked fine). I previously tried to add the filter mapping to my web.xml but it seems its not mandatory anymore with Primefaces 4